# Como seleccion el mismo atributo de una tabla padre para dos tablas hijas

Tags: mysql

[image: Tablas de la BBDD]
Quisiera en una misma consulta mostrar el apellido y nombre de un veterinario y el apellido y nombre de un cliente. Si selecciono Personas.nombre solo muestra el nombre de un cliente, y Clientes.nombre me da error. Quisiera saber como poder diferenciarlos hasta ahora solo pude mostrar los DNI de cada uno

```
     SELECT 
 Clientes.dni AS 'DNI Cliente',Personas.nombre AS Cliente,Veterinarios.dni AS 'DNI Veterinarios', Personas.nombre AS Veterinarios,
 Turnos.fechaInicio AS 'Fecha de Inicio', Turnos.nombreServicio AS 'Tipo de Atencion' 
 FROM Personas JOIN Clientes
 ON Personas.dni = Clientes.dni
 JOIN Mascotas
 ON Clientes.dni = Mascotas.dniCliente 
 JOIN Turnos JOIN VeterinarioAtiendeTurno JOIN Veterinarios
 ON Mascotas.dniCliente = Turnos.dniCliente 
 AND VeterinarioAtiendeTurno.dniCliente = Turnos.dniCliente 
 AND VeterinarioAtiendeTurno.dniVeterinarios = Veterinarios.dni
 JOIN Salas
 ON Turnos.nombreSala = Salas.nombreSala
 WHERE DATE(fechaInicio) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2022-12-31' AND Salas.nombreSala = '05'
 ORDER BY fechaInicio ASC;
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon un ejemplo de como quieres q te salgan los resultados que esperas

Comment: Beatriz, además de lo que te puedan comentar como respuesta directamente, te recomendaría también que NUNCA utilices un DNI como Clave primaria de una tabla... Es un campo que se puede repetir para personas diferentes, y además conceptualmente estás cerrando la puerta a gente sin DNI (que no es una propiedad de todas las personas, sino de un subconjunto), como extranjeros que tengan otro tipo de documentación (NIE, Pasaportes, etc).

Answer (score 0):

A falta de algunos datos, creo que puedo resumir la consulta a lo siguiente:

Una persona puede ser un veterinario o un cliente. Para conocer los datos de ambos, debes hacer `INNER JOIN` en veterinarios y clientes a la tabla de personas.

```
SELECT b.dni AS 'DNI Cliente', a.nombre AS Cliente, c.dni AS 'DNI Veterinario', a.nombre AS Veterinario
FROM personas a
INNER JOIN clientes b ON a.dni = b.dni
INNER JOIN veterinarios c ON a.dni = c.dni
```

Con esto obtendrías todos los valores de ambas tablas.

Sin embargo, creo que la consulta no se enfoca en estas dos tablas sino en turnos y salas, por lo que deberías iniciar la consulta con esas tablas y posteriormente relacionar los veterinarios de turno en la sala 5 entre las fechas 2019-01-01 y 2022-12-31 y finalmente los clientes atendidos.

Te sugiero que intentes reordenar la consulta para obtener mejores resultados.

Creo que con la siguiente consulta puedes obtener el resultado que buscas:

```
SELECT turnos.dniCliente AS 'DNI Cliente', cliente.nombre AS Cliente, turnos.dniVeterinarios AS 'DNI Veterinarios', veterinario.nombre AS Veterinarios, turnos.fechaInicio AS 'Fecha de Inicio', turnos.nombreServicio AS 'Tipo de Atencion'
FROM turnos
INNER JOIN salas ON turnos.nombreSala = salas.nombreSala
INNER JOIN personas AS cliente ON turnos.dniCliente = personas.dni
INNER JOIN veterinarios AS veterinario ON turnos.dniVeterinarios = personas.dni
WHERE DATE(turnos.fechaInicio) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2022-12-31'
AND salas.nombreSala = '05'
ORDER BY turnos.fechaInicio ASC;
```